# I am trying to change a background image of div using php and jquery.php variable not getting the value

Tags: php, jquery, css, mysql

I wrote the code for changing the background image of a div. I am able to upload the image and image is visible in the folder. The image path is getting uploaded in mysql database. But the image is not displaying as background in the div. The php variable value(location) for the specified path of image is not passing to the div. Can any one please let me know my mistake?

```
<?php

session_start();

include_once ('dataconnect.php');

$db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "productiondata");

$uid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$username = $_SESSION['user_name'];

if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {

    global $location;

    $imagename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];

    $imagepath = "images/";

    $location = $imagepath . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "$imagepath" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);


    $sql = "INSERT INTO image(user_id,imagepath,imagename) VALUES('$uid','$imagepath','$imagename')";


    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);

    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM image";


    $query1 = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql1);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query1)) {

        $imagename = $row['imagename'];

        $imagepath = $row['imagepath'];

        echo $location;

    }

}
```

jquery code

```
$('document').ready(function () {


            $('.js_p-uploader').click(function () {

                $('#file').click();

                $('#file').change(function (e) {

                    e.preventDefault();

                    var blob = this.files[0];

                    var formData = new FormData();

                    formData.append('file', blob);

                    $.ajax({

                       url: "profile.php",

                        type: "POST",

                        data: formData,

                        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",

                        processData: false,

                        contentType: false,

                        success: function (location) {



                        }


                    });

                });

            });


        });

div class="profile-cover-wrapper" style="background-image:url('?php echo 

$location ;?');"input type="file" id="file" name ="file"
```

Comment: is that an error on the last line due to typing in SO or are the < and > actually missing from your code <?php echo $location; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Returned data from an Ajax call cannot be used outside, or cannot be used as a PHP variable. What you can do is to change the `src` attribute of your `<img>` inside the `success: function()`:

```
// AJAX CALL HERE
success: function(location) {
    $('.profile-cover-wrapper').css("background-image", "url("+location+")");
}
```

Comment: this is not working.  ().html() is  working but it showing as image and not as background.   If I wants to use it as php variable how code. Do you have any example. I searched in the net but not able to get.

Comment: @SunilKumarReddy Are those in a same file? And the `<div class="profile-cover-wrapper"` already exist in your html file? You could show your HTML file so I can adjust my answer

Comment: hi  thanks Logan . its working now. changed some styles.